# See the header position of a BIG file

Tags: file, utilities

sometimes, we got a BIG file, but we don't know its file type. so we need to use a tool to peek the very first bytes of the file to find out its file type.

but the file is too big to the normal text editor, i have to wait for a long time!

P.S. I need tools, not the code.

Comment: are you asking for the code to write a tool that reads the first few bytes of the file?

Comment: i don't need the code, i need the tool to use!

Comment: in windows, use this:http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools on any reasonable *nix box are:

- `file`: knows a lot of magic headers and detects the type of a file.
- `head`: reads first several lines or bytes of a file.
- `tail`: reads last several bytes or lines of a file; some files have metainfo at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [xxd](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/1%3axxd):

```
xxd -l 10 your-file
```

This displays the first 10 octets of `your-file`